# Display of an calculator like Texas Instruments or CASIO: suggestions

Tags: adobe-illustrator, inkscape, fonts, pdf, software-recommendation

**My question is this**: I would reproduce the screen of a graphic calculator like the image below:

[image: https://services.math.duke.edu/education/prep02/teams/prep-16/tivertex_files/image006.gif]

what might be the possible solutions?

I use `LaTeX` ([related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/558351/search-for-a-package-to-generate-graphic-displays-of-calculators)) and I remember that there was a specific package. Now supposing that I use the package [tipfr-doc.pdf](https://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/ctan/graphics/pgf/contrib/tipfr/doc/tipfr-doc.pdf), the graph

[image]

is incomplete. In fact it is without pixel and labels. I have download the fonts [Texas Instruments](https://www.dafontfree.net/freefonts-texas-instruments-ti-84-series-f90829.htm)
and I complete the drawing?

What are the suggestions how to quickly create a file vectorial `.pdf` similar to the initial image?

Thank you very much to all users. I hope that someone might help me.

Comment: Why dont you use a ti85 emulator? Anyway your in wrong place ask tex stackexhange.

Comment: @joojaa What is ti85 emulator? Please can you help me, to have an answer? Thank you very much.

Comment: Its a software that runs ti85 on your computer graohics and all.

Comment: Read: https://askubuntu.com/questions/504003/how-to-install-virtual-ti-85

Comment: @joojaa Is it this? https://education.ti.com/en/products/computer-software/ti-connect-sw. But exists an alternative to the sofware, for your opinion? But Tilem - TI Linux Emulator is for LinuX? I use W7 or W8, W10 OS.

Comment: Its not the same. You can download a windows version on tilem homepage

Comment: @joojaa I'm curious to know if any of you would show me something to see if with external software you could create the graphic of the initial image but vectorial.

Comment: @dowvoter: What is the meaning of your downvote? Please, explain it.

Comment: I don't think my comment will help but In inkscape there is a filter "Pixelize" which gives that effect but the effect is not much clear

Comment: You could also check videos/articles about Pixel art on Adobe illustrator: https://design.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-pixel-art-icons-in-adobe-illustrator--cms-22941

Comment: @Navaro Hi, and thank you very much for your reply. Do you put your answer, please? I hope that it is possible.

Comment: Not asked, but I like to have my graphs as sharp. The crunched and already deleted answer showed an easy way to get them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not have TI-85 emulator draw it as pixel art as suggested already by others or create it in LaTeX as you have already done.

When you have a bitmap image like the black one vectorize it.

Start in GIMP or Photoshop by increasing the pixel dimensions to Nx100%, at least to 400% with nearest neighbour resampling for no blur. Paste the result to Illustrator and trace it with the highest accuracy:

[image]

In small size it looks good but in bigger size it's far from perfect:

[image]

Apply Object > Live Trace > Expand and Object > Path > Simplify to get perfect straight edges. See the dialog:

[image]

Now it's like the original, but sharp also in high zoom. The rightmost is the vectorized version. I Ungrouped it and changed the fill color of a part just to show it's a vector:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much...always...but where is TI-85 emulator in the web (eventually)? Do you know, please?

Comment: I haven't one. My calculator emulator tries to be a HP's postfix notation model. I prefer that system to keep things in order. But start by checking this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lXIqazmkFwo . It shows that setting up a TI-85 emulator needs much more than downloading a program & running it.

Comment: Thank a lot again....and another way.

Comment: Tgere is a alternate way that does not need scaling or tracing and works well because the resolution is low. Use object mosaic then merge all blacks with pathfinder and path simplify to get rid of excess points, repeat for or delete white. In this case its more accurate.

Comment: @Sebastiano The preceding comment by user joojaa should be taken seriously. Applying in Illustrator Object > Create Object Mosaic, size=the image pixel dimensions does the job if you have a machine from this century. Ungroup, select one white rectangle, apply Select >  Same > Fill color and press DEL to kill the unnecessary white objects.

Comment: @Sebastiano seemingly you also want somehow realistic look. It's easy if you can make layered images. Open this 
 https://www.dropbox.com/s/qc2d5vqlsob0dfp/calculator.psd?dl=0 in GIMP, Photoshop or Photopea and see the layers. They are from the top the formula (=crap), partially transparent blurred and moved copy as a shadow and a gradient background for realistic light.

Comment: @user287001 Thank you very very much for this comment that I have appreciated much much. Your previous answer it is very very good. Actually I'm using OS W7 32-bit (2004) :-) and I have not installed nothing of very heavy because my device becomes very slow. I know GIMP and Photoshop but no Photopea. If you prefer you can add another answer.

Comment: Photopea is a web service which can be run with a browser. It has a great part of Photoshop's functionality for RGB images, for ex. adjustment layers, layer masks and layer styles.

Comment: @user287001 Hi, truly I have not understand your downvote! It is very strange.

Comment: The downvote I got is a revenge for answering here as a comment to your other LCD display question which was closed. Someone had already decided that question should not get answers.